# Why is (int)((int *)0 + 4) == 16?

Tags: c

I have tested this, `k` is 16, but why?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int k = (int)((int *)0 + 4);
    printf("%d", k);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not? The behavior is undefined anyway. Pointer arithmetic on a null pointer is illegal in C.

Comment: What do you expect? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Important note:** Pointer arithmetic on a pointer that does not point to an array is undefined behavior. You can get 16, but you can also get a crash, for example, if the implementation chooses to produce a trap representation for the result.

This is pointer arithmetic: when you add a number `x` to a pointer to `T`, numeric value that corresponds to the pointer is increased by `x * sizeof(T)`.

In your case, the numeric value of the pointer is zero, `x` is 4, and `sizeof(int)` is also 4. `4*4` yields 16.

Comment: Pointer to non-array object is defined to behave like a pointer to array of size 1 ... so I think your cases are limited to null and invalid pointers

Comment: "This is pointer arithmetic: when you add a number x to a pointer to T, numeric value that corresponds to the pointer is increased by x * sizeof(T)." I didn't notice this point before, thanks for your explain.

Comment: @Charles Because this is UB, anything can happen. You happen to get `16`, but as well could your harddrive be formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer arithmetic in C use the type's size as an unit; adding 1 to int* will make it advance by 4 (assuming int is 32bit).

EDIT: pointer arithmetic on invalid pointers (including NULL) is undefined behavior.